# Django app not running after installing askbot

Tags: python, django, askbot

The application was working perfectly fine before installing askbot. I checked their docs and installed askbot as a pluggable app. And I had also merged the settings and urls. Now the forum part(askbot app) is working fine but the other part including the index have crashed.

The error is as follows:

```
    AttributeError at /
    'Template' object has no attribute 'nodelist'
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
    Django Version: 1.3.7
    Exception Type: AttributeError
    Exception Value:    
    'Template' object has no attribute 'nodelist'
    Exception Location: /home/djangouser/Documents/djprojs/qnet/dj1.3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py in render, line 116
    Python Executable:  /home/djangouser/Documents/djprojs/qnet/dj1.3/bin/python
    Python Version: 2.7.3
    Python Path:    
    ['/home/djangouser/Documents/Workspace/Qnet/Qnet',
     '/home/djangouser/Documents/djprojs/qnet/dj1.3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg',
     '/home/djangouser/Documents/Workspace/Qnet',
     '/home/djangouser/Documents/Workspace/Qnet/Qnet/peer',
     '/home/djangouser/Documents/Workspace/Qnet/Qnet',
     '/home/djangouser/Documents/djprojs/qnet/dj1.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stdimage',
     '/home/djangouser/Documents/djprojs/qnet/dj1.3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg',
     '/usr/share/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_2.7.0.2012080220/pysrc/pydev_sitecustomize',
     '/home/djangouser/Documents/djprojs/qnet/dj1.3/lib/python2.7',
     '/home/djangouser/Documents/djprojs/qnet/dj1.3/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
     '/home/djangouser/Documents/djprojs/qnet/dj1.3/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
     '/home/djangouser/Documents/djprojs/qnet/dj1.3/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
     '/home/djangouser/Documents/djprojs/qnet/dj1.3/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
     '/home/djangouser/Documents/djprojs/qnet/dj1.3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
     '/home/djangouser/Documents/Workspace/sampleproj/sampleproj',
     '/home/djangouser/Documents/djprojs/qnet/dj1.3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL',
     '/home/djangouser/Documents/djprojs/qnet/dj1.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg',
     '/home/djangouser/Documents/djprojs/qnet/dj1.3/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
     '/home/djangouser/Documents/djprojs/qnet/dj1.3/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
     '/home/djangouser/Documents/djprojs/qnet/dj1.3/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
     '/home/djangouser/Documents/djprojs/qnet/dj1.3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/askbot/deps']
    Server time:    Fri, 1 Mar 2013 05:44:14 -0600
```

The traceback is as follows

```
    Environment:


    Request Method: GET
    Request URL: http://localhost:8000/

    Django Version: 1.3.7
    Python Version: 2.7.3
    Installed Applications:
    ['longerusername',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'pagination',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'askbot',
    'south',
    'askbot.deps.livesettings',
    'keyedcache',
    'robots',
    'django_countries',
    'djcelery',
    'djkombu',
    'followit',
    'tinymce',
    'group_messaging',
    'postman',
    'peer']
    Installed Middleware:
    ('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'pagination.middleware.PaginationMiddleware',
    'askbot.middleware.anon_user.ConnectToSessionMessagesMiddleware',
    'askbot.middleware.forum_mode.ForumModeMiddleware',
    'askbot.middleware.cancel.CancelActionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.transaction.TransactionMiddleware',
    'askbot.middleware.view_log.ViewLogMiddleware',
    'askbot.middleware.spaceless.SpacelessMiddleware')


    Traceback:
    File "/home/djangouser/Documents/djprojs/qnet/dj1.3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
    111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
    File "/home/djangouser/Documents/Workspace/Qnet/Qnet/peer/views.py" in index
    71.     return render_to_response('index.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    File "/home/djangouser/Documents/djprojs/qnet/dj1.3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render_to_response
    20.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)
    File "/home/djangouser/Documents/djprojs/qnet/dj1.3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
    188.         return t.render(context_instance)
    File "/home/djangouser/Documents/djprojs/qnet/dj1.3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
    123.             return self._render(context)
    File "/home/djangouser/Documents/djprojs/qnet/dj1.3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
    117.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
    File "/home/djangouser/Documents/djprojs/qnet/dj1.3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
    744.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
    File "/home/djangouser/Documents/djprojs/qnet/dj1.3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_node
    757.         return node.render(context)
    File "/home/djangouser/Documents/djprojs/qnet/dj1.3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
    116.         for node in compiled_parent.nodelist:

    Exception Type: AttributeError at /
    Exception Value: 'Template' object has no attribute 'nodelist'
```

The contents of settings.py are 
        # Django settings for QNET project.

```
    ###FOR ASKBOT
    import os.path
    import logging
    import sys
    import askbot
    import site


    #this line is added so that we can import pre-packaged askbot dependencies
    ASKBOT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(askbot.__file__))
    site.addsitedir(os.path.join(ASKBOT_ROOT, 'deps'))
    INTERNAL_IPS = ('127.0.0.1',)
    ###END ASKBOT


    DEBUG = True
    TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False;#keep false when debugging jinja2 templates

    ADMINS = (
        # ('', ''),
        )

    MANAGERS = ADMINS

    DATABASES = {
    'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
            'NAME': 'qnetfinal',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
            'USER': 'django',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
            'PASSWORD': 'djangodb',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
            'HOST': '127.0.0.1',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
            'PORT': '5432',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
            }
            }

    ###FOR ASKBOT
    #outgoing mail server settings
    SERVER_EMAIL = ''
    DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = ''
    EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
    EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
    EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = ''
    EMAIL_HOST=''
    EMAIL_PORT=''
    EMAIL_USE_TLS=False
    EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

    #incoming mail settings
    #after filling out these settings - please
    #go to the site's live settings and enable the feature
    #"Email settings" -> "allow asking by email"
    #
    #   WARNING: command post_emailed_questions DELETES all 
    #            emails from the mailbox each time
    #            do not use your personal mail box here!!!
    #
    IMAP_HOST = ''
    IMAP_HOST_USER = ''
    IMAP_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
    IMAP_PORT = ''
    IMAP_USE_TLS = False
    ###END ASKBOT

    # Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
    # See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

    # Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
    # http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
    # although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
    # On Unix systems, a value of None will cause Django to use the same
    # timezone as the operating system.
    # If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your
    # system time zone.
    TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

    # Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
    # http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
    LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

    SITE_ID = 1

    # If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
    # to load the internationalization machinery.
    USE_I18N = True

    # If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
    # calendars according to the current locale
    USE_L10N = True

    # Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
    # Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
    MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/djangouser/Desktop/QNET/media'

    # URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
    # trailing slash.
    # Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

    # Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
    # Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
    # in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
    # Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
    STATIC_ROOT = '/home/djangouser/Desktop/QNET/static/'

    # URL prefix for static files.
    # Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'

    ###FOR ASKBOT
    PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    ###END ASKBOT

    # URL prefix for admin static files -- CSS, JavaScript and images.
    # Make sure to use a trailing slash.
    # Examples: "http://foo.com/static/admin/", "/static/admin/".
    ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'

    # Additional locations of static files
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        '/home/djangouser/Desktop/QNET/static/site/',
    ###FOR ASKBOT
    ('default/media', os.path.join(ASKBOT_ROOT, 'media')),
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "static"),
    ###END ASKBOT
        # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
        # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
        # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
        )

    # List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
    # various locations.
    STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
        'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    #    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
    )

    # Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
    SECRET_KEY = '+zme3dsnpuq^j$(mjlm3p$2&^p0np$(z8$_kr)n841z@32ny6+'

    # List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
    TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    ###FOR ASKBOT
    'askbot.skins.loaders.Loader',
    ###END ASKBOT
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    #     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
    )

    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'pagination.middleware.PaginationMiddleware',
    ###FOR ASKBOT
        #below is askbot stuff for this tuple
        'askbot.middleware.anon_user.ConnectToSessionMessagesMiddleware',
        'askbot.middleware.forum_mode.ForumModeMiddleware',
        'askbot.middleware.cancel.CancelActionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.transaction.TransactionMiddleware',
        #'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
        'askbot.middleware.view_log.ViewLogMiddleware',
        'askbot.middleware.spaceless.SpacelessMiddleware',
    ###END ASKBOT

    )

    ROOT_URLCONF = 'QNET.urls'

    ###FOR ASKBOT
    #UPLOAD SETTINGS
    FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR = os.path.join(
        os.path.dirname(__file__), 
        'tmp'
        ).replace('\\','/')

    FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS = (
        'django.core.files.uploadhandler.MemoryFileUploadHandler',
        'django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler',
        )
    ASKBOT_ALLOWED_UPLOAD_FILE_TYPES = ('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.bmp', '.png', '.tiff')
    ASKBOT_MAX_UPLOAD_FILE_SIZE = 1024 * 1024 #result in bytes
    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage'

    #ASKBOT_EXTRA_SKINS_DIR = #path to your private skin collection
    #take a look here http://askbot.org/en/question/207/

    TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS= (
    #    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    #    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'postman.context_processors.inbox',
    'askbot.context.application_settings',
        #'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
        'askbot.user_messages.context_processors.user_messages',#must be before auth
        'django.core.context_processors.auth', #this is required for the admin app
        'django.core.context_processors.csrf', #necessary for csrf protection

        )

    TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
        '/home/djangouser/Desktop/QNET/templates'
        # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
        # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
        # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
        )

    # to provide our get_profile()
    AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE='Humans.Human'

    ###Login decorator
    LOGIN_URL='/login/'

    #LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL='/profile/'

    ### Postman moderation
    POSTMAN_AUTO_MODERATE_AS = True

    INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ###FOR ASKBOT
    'longerusername',
    ###END ASKBOT
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'pagination',
    ###FOR ASKBOT
        #all of these are needed for the askbot
        # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
        'django.contrib.humanize',
        'django.contrib.sitemaps',
        #'debug_toolbar',
        #Optional, to enable haystack search
        #'haystack',
        'askbot',
    #    'askbot.deps.django_authopenid',
        #'askbot.importers.stackexchange', #se loader
        'south',
        'askbot.deps.livesettings',
        'keyedcache',
        'robots',
        'django_countries',
        'djcelery',
        'djkombu',
        'followit',
        'tinymce',
        'group_messaging',
        #'avatar',#experimental use git clone git://github.com/ericflo/django-avatar.git$
    ###END ASKBOT
    #    'south',
    'postman',
    'Humans',
    'mptt',
    'easy_thumbnails',
    'filer',
    #    'ajax_select',
        # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
        # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
        )

    ####FOR ASKBOT
    #setup memcached for production use!
    #see http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/cache/ for details
    CACHE_BACKEND = 'locmem://'
    #needed for django-keyedcache
    CACHE_TIMEOUT = 6000
    #sets a special timeout for livesettings if you want to make them different
    LIVESETTINGS_CACHE_TIMEOUT = CACHE_TIMEOUT
    CACHE_PREFIX = 'askbot' #make this unique
    CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ANONYMOUS_ONLY = True
    #If you use memcache you may want to uncomment the following line to enable memcached based sessions
    #SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cached_db'

    AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
        'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    #    'askbot.deps.django_authopenid.backends.AuthBackend',
    )

    ##logging settings
    #LOG_FILENAME = 'askbot.log'
    #logging.basicConfig(
    #    filename=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'log', LOG_FILENAME),
    #    level=logging.CRITICAL,
    #    format='%(pathname)s TIME: %(asctime)s MSG: %(filename)s:%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d %(message)s',
    #)
    #
    ############################
    ##
    ##   this will allow running your forum with url like http://site.com/forum
    ##
    ##   ASKBOT_URL = 'forums/'
    ##
    ASKBOT_URL = 'forums/' #no leading slash, default = '' empty string
    ASKBOT_TRANSLATE_URL = True #translate specific URLs
    _ = lambda v:v #fake translation function for the login url
    #LOGIN_URL = '/%s%s%s' % (ASKBOT_URL,_('account/'),_('signin/'))
    LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = ASKBOT_URL #adjust, if needed
    #note - it is important that upload dir url is NOT translated!!!
    #also, this url must not have the leading slash
    ALLOW_UNICODE_SLUGS = False
    ASKBOT_USE_STACKEXCHANGE_URLS = False #mimic url scheme of stackexchange

    #Celery Settings
    BROKER_TRANSPORT = "djkombu.transport.DatabaseTransport"
    CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True

    import djcelery
    djcelery.setup_loader()
    DOMAIN_NAME = ''

    CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = '_csrf'
    #https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/csrf/
    #CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = DOMAIN_NAME

    #STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "static")
    #STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    #    ('default/media', os.path.join(ASKBOT_ROOT, 'media')),
    #)

    RECAPTCHA_USE_SSL = True

    #HAYSTACK_SETTINGS
    ENABLE_HAYSTACK_SEARCH = False
    HAYSTACK_SITECONF = 'askbot.search.haystack'
    #more information
    #http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v1.2.7/settings.html
    HAYSTACK_SEARCH_ENGINE = 'simple'

    TINYMCE_COMPRESSOR = True
    TINYMCE_SPELLCHECKER = False
    TINYMCE_JS_ROOT = os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, 'default/media/js/tinymce/')
    TINYMCE_URL = STATIC_URL + 'default/media/js/tinymce/'
    TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'plugins': 'askbot_imageuploader,askbot_attachment',
    'convert_urls': False,
    'theme': 'advanced',
    'content_css': STATIC_URL + 'default/media/style/tinymce/content.css',
    'force_br_newlines': True,
    'force_p_newlines': False,
    'forced_root_block': '',
    'mode' : 'textareas',
    'oninit': "function(){ tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(askbot['data']['editorContent'] || ''); }",
    'plugins': 'askbot_imageuploader,askbot_attachment',
    'theme_advanced_toolbar_location' : 'top',
    'theme_advanced_toolbar_align': 'left',
    'theme_advanced_buttons1': 'bold,italic,underline,|,bullist,numlist,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,askbot_imageuploader,askbot_attachment',
    'theme_advanced_buttons2': '',
    'theme_advanced_buttons3' : '',
    'theme_advanced_path': False,
    'theme_advanced_resizing': True,
    'theme_advanced_resize_horizontal': False,
    'theme_advanced_statusbar_location': 'bottom',
    'width': '723',
    'height': '250'
    }

    #delayed notifications, time in seconds, 15 mins by default
    NOTIFICATION_DELAY_TIME = 60 * 15 

    GROUP_MESSAGING = {
    'BASE_URL_GETTER_FUNCTION': 'askbot.models.user_get_profile_url',
    'BASE_URL_PARAMS': {'section': 'messages', 'sort': 'inbox'}
    }

    ###END ASKBOT

    # A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
    # performed by this configuration is to send an email to
    # the site admins on every HTTP 500 error.
    # See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
    # more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
    LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
    'mail_admins': {
    'level': 'ERROR',
    'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
    }
    },
    'loggers': {
    'django.request': {
    'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
    'level': 'ERROR',
    'propagate': True,
    },
    }
    }
```

The contents of urls.py are

```
    from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.conf.urls.defaults import handler404
    from django.conf.urls.defaults import handler500
    from django.conf.urls.defaults import include
    from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns
    from django.conf.urls.defaults import url
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.contrib import admin

    import admin_auth

    admin.autodiscover()

    if getattr(settings, 'ASKBOT_MULTILINGUAL', False) == True:
        from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
        urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
            (r'%s' % settings.ASKBOT_URL, include('askbot.urls'))
            )
    else:
        urlpatterns = patterns('',
            (r'%s' % settings.ASKBOT_URL, include('askbot.urls'))
            )

        urlpatterns += patterns('',
            (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
        #(r'^cache/', include('keyedcache.urls')), - broken views disable for now
        (r'^settings/', include('askbot.deps.livesettings.urls')),
        (r'^followit/', include('followit.urls')),
        (r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
        (r'^robots.txt$', include('robots.urls')),
        url( # TODO: replace with django.conf.urls.static ?
            r'^%s(?P<path>.*)$' % settings.MEDIA_URL[1:], 
            'django.views.static.serve',
            {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT.replace('\\','/')},
            ),
        url(r'^register/', 'Humans.views.HumansRegistration'),
        url(r'^$', 'Humans.views.index'),
        url(r'^messages/', include('postman.urls')),
        url(r'^logout/', 'Humans.views.LogoutRequest'),
        url(r'^login/', 'Humans.views.LoginRequest'),
        )

        if 'rosetta' in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
            urlpatterns += patterns('',
                url(r'^rosetta/', include('rosetta.urls')),
        )
```

Please help me with this. I tried googling a lot, but of no use. And I couldn't post this in the askbot forums too as I'm low on karma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Askbot uses Jinja2 templates, it's possible that your 'index.html' template, which - I am guessing - is a Django template, extends askbot's "base" template - a Jinja2 template.

It seems that the error is not a template parsing error, but an API error. It might happen when both the top level template and the base template are found and parsed correctly, but they can't be put together due to the incomatible internal api's of the templating engines.

Maybe a solution is to create a Django version of the base template and put it in a different directory.

Askbot does work when part of the projects uses Django templates - for example - our /settings/ url maps to the `livesettings` app, which uses Django templates and both work fine, but they use different base templates.

For a quick test - create a simple base template and use it for the `index.html`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think that was the problem. I renamed my base.html to another name and modified all my template files to extend to this template.

Comment: I struggled with this for a full day. and found another solution http://concentricsky.com/blog/2013/jan/extending-jinja2-django-templates  What do you think Evgeny?

Comment: Thanks for sharing @Eugene, can be very useful. I personally - if I had enough time - would just switch the templates to Jinja2, but if there is shortage of time what you suggest would be very handy.